# Inserting the filename before the first line of a text file - File extension

Tags: bash, awk

```
~$ awk -i inplace -v ORS='\r\n' 'FNR==1{print FILENAME}1' *
```

This works great.

But I want to exclude the file extension.

```
.... sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", FILENAME) ...
```

I don't know how to mix it. Or is there another way?

How should I fix it?

Comment: It's unusual to want to read input that ends in `\n` only but generate output that ends in `\r\n` - are you sure you want to do that? As written if your input file ends in `\r\n` then your output will end in `\r\r\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution(without using a new variable and editing FILENAME variable itself):*** Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. I would recommend to run this program on a single file once then run on all the files because you are doing in-place updates, once you are happy with that file's update then run your command on all the files.

```
awk -i inplace -v ORS='\r\n' 'FNR==1{sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",FILENAME);print FILENAME}1' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -i inplace -v ORS='\r\n' '
FNR==1{
match(FILENAME,/.*\./)
print substr(FILENAME,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
}
1' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution(Using a variable for FILENAME and we could use file's name later on if needed):*** OR DO NOT change `FILENAME` default variable rather create a temp variable which has its filename in it so that in case we need to use file's name in later of program we could use it, try like:

```
awk -i inplace -v ORS='\r\n' '
FNR==1{
file=FILENAME
sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",file)
print file
}
1' Input_file
```

OR we could use `match` function also as follows:

```
awk -i inplace -v ORS='\r\n' '
FNR==1{
file=FILENAME
match(file,/.*\./)
print substr(file,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
}
1' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Change `Input_file` to `*` or your file's extensions to pass it to your `awk` program.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you can use `gensub`:

```sh
awk -i inplace -v ORS='\r\n' 'FNR==1{print gensub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", 1, FILENAME)}1' *
```

The `gensub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", 1, FILENAME)` means:

- `/\.[^.]+$/` - finds `.` followed with one or more non-dot chars till end of string
- `""` - replaces with an empty string
- `1` - searches only once
- `FILENAME` - this is the input text.

See [`gawk` string functions reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).